# i want to have a specific array list for an object as a class attribute java

Tags: java, arrays, class

i am trying to have an array of classes with 10 memebers

```
package localpackage;

import localpackage.Class;
public class School {
    int code;
    String name;
    Class[] classes = new Class[10];
    public School(int _code, String _name, Class _classes[]){
        code = _code;
        name = _name;
        classes = _classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want my constructor to only accept a list of 10

Comment: Just a hint that java naming conventions recommend not using "_" before variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677249/why-we-add-underscore-before-variable-name

Comment: @javi3y again: what is your question? if you don't want the other parameters, delete them. If you want the array to be exactly sized ten, throw an exception if it has any other size

Comment: this is my first time writing java code sorry i didn't know i shouldn't do it

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to ensure in the constructor that the array classes[] has a length of 10 ?

Comment: @Stultuske ok thanks but how can i do it

Comment: @Kujoen exactly

Comment: @javi3y I gave a detailed description of what to do for both cases. At this point you aren't even clear what it is you are trying to achieve. Try and implement it yourself first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to ensure a minimum size of a variable in the constructor.
Take a look here, you will find what you need:

[set minimum size of a variable array in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996476/set-minimum-size-of-a-variable-array-in-the-constructor)

To name some of the solutions here, you can either directly check it with something like:

```
    if (name.length() < 12){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("name must have at least 12 characters");
    }
```

Or you can move the check to a seperate Method and call it from the constructor.

Finally, you can use annotations like:

```
class Kingdom {
    @MinLength(12)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

But then you need to create the Annotation class and implement the behaviour yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use ArrayList and define your 10 items :

```java
     List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(3);
        arr.add(4);
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(6);
        arr.add(7);
        arr.add(8);
        arr.add(9);
        arr.add(10);
```

Or from array :

```java
         ArrayList<String> gfg = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
```

Or use a nCopy  :

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, new ItemsToCreate());
```

Or you can use a for loop

[How can I initialize an ArrayList with all zeroes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java/5600690)

Comment: This will probably be usefull for him to ensure he can pass arrays of a min length, however, he was asking about how to enforce variables passed to the constructor have a minimum length.

Comment: Oh, I didnt saw that. Hope it will help anyway.